# Congrats to all the new Salesforce MVPs

Tags: discussion, mvp, recognition

Its great to see so many awesome people getting recognised and included in the Salesforce MVP community..

and its a pleasure to see some of our SFSE contributors in the list.. awesome work everyone.. :-)

here's the [new MVP list](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/salesforce-mvps-2016.html?d=70130000000tP4G) if anyone missed it..

Comment: Thanks everyone for all support and love .This site has been awesome and lets keep doing the awesome work of sharing and spreading knowledge :).I am truly honored and blessed to be a part of MVP program and would keep doing my best to answer precisely .

Comment: It is an honour and a pleasure to be nominated and become a Salesforce MVP. I will continue to do my best to help the community here and elsewhere for the next year and beyond! Thanks to everyone for making this possible.

Comment: It's definitely an unexpected and welcome honor indeed. I do what I do to help people whenever I can anyways, but it's definitely nice to be recognized once in a great while, too.

Comment: Well deserved and congrats to all of you guys! :)

Comment: Congrats! Can any of you who've done it before explain what's involved and what it takes to be worthy of this honor? Was SFSE a key component of anyone's candidacy, or does it take outside accomplishments also?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Salesforce published that article [Top 5 Things to Know About How We Choose Our MVPs](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/how-we-choose-salesforce-mvps.html)

Comment: I'm amazed by the group of people who got in this round, I can't believe my name is side by side with some of you! Thanks, SFSE!

Comment: @DanielBallinger I guess what I was trying to get at was, is just SFSE enough? I would like to join the ranks some day!

Comment: @AdrianLarson In theory it would be possible based of SFSE community participation alone, but I think it would be more probable with wider activity. If you are active in one or more of the following it will help - blogs, twitter, user groups, conference presentations. You need to be nominated and then recognized by the existing MVPs and the "Salesforce program stackholders". If your activity over the last year stands out to both those groups the MVP award should follow in time.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the more you do, and the  more broadly recognized the contribution, the more likely you will be accepted into the program. A good first step is to find an MVP that you admire to mentor you. You can also join the influitive champions program. If you (or anyone) have interest in pursuing either, dm me: pchittum-at-salesforce-dot-com.

Comment: Very impressive list - without those names and their contributions, I wouldn't know 20% of what I do now about SFDC

Answer (score 10):

HUge congrats people... it makes me happy to see good SFSE contributors being recognised for their work on here because I still think it's the best way to get help around (yeah, maybe I'm a bit biased) :)

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to all!!! Special shout to my buddy Mohith :)

Comment: thanks calvin :)